# Laurent series of $ \frac{z-12}{z^2 + z - 6}$ valid for $|z-1| >1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{z-12}{z^2 + z - 6}$ valid for 
$(a) \ \ \ 1 < |z-1| <4$

$(b) \ \ \ |z-1| > 1$

$(c) \ \ \ |z-1| < 4$

We have $$f(z)=   f(z) = \frac{z-12}{z^2 + z - 6} = \frac{-2}{z-2}  + \frac{3}{z+3}$$

I know the answer for $(a)$

$$f(z) = -2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}} + 3 \sum_{n =0}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}\frac{(z-1)^{n}}{4^{n+1}}$$

How Can I find the Laurent series for $(b)$ and $(c)$ ?

Thank you ...

Comment: Did you mean to write for $(b)$ $ |z-1|<1$ and for $(c)$ $|z-1|>4$?

Comment: No, I mean exactly $(b) |z-1| >1$ and $(c) |z-1| < 4$ I know the answer If it was $|z-1|<1$ and $|z-1|>4$ . This is  question no $3$ page $292$ in the book "complex analysis with applications " by S.PONNUSAMY

Comment: It seems the author typoed the $<$ and $>$ signs or the answer is "doesn't exist" for b and c

Comment: How do you do it for $|z-1|>4$. It's easy to extract a series for $\frac{3}{z+3}$, but I have no idea how to come up with a series for $\frac{-2}{z-2}$